# Merge two columns of bits to one column

Tags: arrays, matlab

In Matlab, how can I merge two bits from two columns (each column consist of one bit) into one column, for example:

```
X = [1,0;0,1;1,1;0,0;1,1;0,0]
```

The desired result is:

```
X = [10;01;11;00;11;00]
```

Comment: What is your data type? Double?

Comment: Please clarify on what the data type of `X` is.  What you are asking for can't be done with just `double` arrays.  For example, the `01` will be displayed as `1` and the `00` will be displayed as `0`.

Comment: @Ander Biguri , Yes the data is Double, and I want to make it as 1x1 array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be thinking too easy here, but what about this:

```
10*X(:,1)+X(:,2)
```

Note that it will not actually show things like 01 as this is simplified to 1.

If you really want to show 01, you may need to process it as text:

```
Y=num2str(X)
Y(:,[1 end])
```

Comment: Both methods work for X as decimal and as logical, but you will want to pay attention to the type of output that you need.

Comment: @othmannoor Good to hear that! If you want to indicate that you have found what you are looking for you can tick the mark left of the answer that you want to accept.

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution would be:

```
b = char(X+48)
```

If the **char array** is inconvenient, you can transform it to a cell array:

```
bcell = cellstr(b)
```

Comment: Of course it is a matter of personal preference, but I find `char(X+'0')` more easy to read.